# How to fix error Call to undefined function link_to_route() laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

First I am sorry my  endlish so bad ,Hi all I am a new of laravel I just studying laravel. and I have problame error with link_to_route() function I try to fix and search google but I still can not.and I got error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in cb4e66236ac7f3bb7bc9c7abce945dc30f4b8bf1.php line 33: Call to undefined function link_to_route()
```

and here is my route.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('register',[
        'as' => 'get_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
        ]);
    Route::post('register',[
        'as' => 'post_register',
        'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'
        ]);
});
```

And here is my code nav.blade.php

```
 <li><?php echo link_to_route('get_register', 'Register'); ?></li>
```

Comment: Read http://laravel.io/forum/02-04-2015-laravel-5-error-link-to-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a package named `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"`

In your composer.json file, Write this line

> "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"

Then open `config/app.php` file.

In provider array,Write this line:-

> 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

Next, add these lines to the 'aliases' array:

> 'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
>
> 'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',

This [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) will help you.

Comment: Just a couple of points

2. It's generally a better idea to use `composer require laravelcollective/html` rather than adding it to composer.json manually. This ensures that you always get the latest version

2. You want to be adding `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class` to your provider array, not just `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to update composer after adding "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0" line to composer.json file.
Please use following reference site
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation for more information.